# Problems using PHP to send headers using header()

Tags: php, http, http-headers, httpresponse

I am trying to do a small application that send a HTTP request to a website, and gets a HTTP reply. I use the status on the header to see what  happened with the request. The code is quiet simple, and short, but somehow I still get the default `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` instead of my personalize message when everything goes fine.

Note: Request can have 2 or 3 parts. 2 parts only authenticates and third part means something should be added. If you have any comments of any other part of the code, I am happy to see them too. 
note2: token is username, because not sure if I will really need it or not later.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['usernameUS'])&&isset($_POST['passwordUS'])&&!empty($_POST['usernameUS'])&&!empty($_POST['passwordUS']))  {
    try {
        $hostname = "";
        $database = "";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT salt, password FROM users WHERE account=:account");
        $stmt->bindParam(':account', $_POST['usernameUS'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $passwordUS = $pdo->quote($_POST['passwordUS']);
        $Blowfish_Pre = '$2a$05$';
        $Blowfish_End = '$';
        $bcrypt_salt = $Blowfish_Pre . $row['salt'] . $Blowfish_End;
        $hashed_password = crypt($passwordUS, $bcrypt_salt);
        if ($hashed_password == $row['password']) {
            if(isset($_POST['message']))    {
                try {
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO newData (ip , account , token, message) VALUES (:ip, :username, :token, :message)");
                    $stmt->bindParam(':ip', $_POST['usernameUS'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['usernameUS'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':token', $_POST['usernameUS'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':message', $_POST['message'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $value = $stmt->execute();
                    if($value)  {
                        header("HTTP/1.1 200 Added");
                    }
                    else {
                        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Could not add information");
                    }
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Cannot insert message", false);
                    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
                }
            }
                header("HTTP/1.1 200 Authenticated", false);
        } 
        else {
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Incorrect Login Information", false);
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Could not connect", false);
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
else {
    header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/' ) ;
}
?>
```

Comment: I suppose that the "do-not-replace" parameter of header() does not work for status headers, only for "named" ones such as "Location: xxx". The line `header("HTTP/1.1 200 Authenticated", false);` does not make any sense to me? However, HTTP status codes are for HTTP status information and not to send custom information. Use the body of the response for that.

Comment: I will try to put my messages on the body of the response, but would still like to know why header("HTTP/1.1 200 Authenticated"); is not being send while the others are.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, but not the explanation.
Using the 200 code, will always be set to "Ok", so if I changed it to 400 then I was able to set my own reply.

Not sure if answering my own questions means that I ask to fast, or that I at least keep looking for the solution :S